# iOS animation: CGAffineTransformMakeScale grows before shrinking

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am having trouble with an animation. The `image` view starts at scale 1. I want to shrink it. The code seems straightforward:

```
image.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity // <<-- seems to have no effect
UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5) 
    }) { (Bool) -> Void in
        // code for next steps
    }
```

The problem: the image first grows to something that seems inversely proportional to the target scale factor (twice for scale 0.5, 10-fold for scale 0.1). Then it shrinks back to the original scale (as if doing what the actual scale transform says). You can see it in the animation: the code is executed after confirmation in the alert view.

[image: why grow before shrink?]

Why does the image grow before shrinking? The initialization of the transform (using `CGAffineTransformIdentity`) seems to have no effect. I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342265/uiview-animation-with-cgaffinetransformmakescale-changes-size-instantly-with-dec) that seems to be about the same problem, but without an answer. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

While looking at the GIF of the animation I created for this question, I noticed that there are other animations that are also happening on the same image: the image slightly rotates at high frequency.

I invalidated the timer responsible for the rotation animation and the scale animation now works fine.

So, the problem was **interference between multiple animations** (a rotation and the scale in question) acting on the same image view.